# How can I enable next and previous Functionality in MPMovieController?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController for playing Videos.
But when I click on next and previous button it dismiss the view.
I've seen tutorials using NSNotification to implement it.
But still I'm not able to Go next and Previous Videos
Here is the code of my app

```
 moviePlayer =
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];


[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playbackChanged)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:moviePlayer];


 - (void)playbackChanged {

     moviePlayer = notification.object;

    switch ([moviePlayer playbackState])
    {
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped:
            NSLog(@"Stopped");
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying:
            NSLog(@"Playing");
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused:
            NSLog(@"Paused");
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted:
            NSLog(@"Interrupted");
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward:
            NSLog(@"Seeking Forward");
            break;
        case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward:
            NSLog(@"Seeking Backward");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this line for *moviePlayer = notification.object;*?

Comment: i seen it on a tutorial.
i am using MPMoviecontroller 1st tym

Comment: Remove the line and try. I'm not sure what the notification is. Where did you instantiate the var?

Comment: Your question needs some more info. i.e. Files are stored locally on the device or accessed through the internet via streaming? And do you have a MediaCollection containing MediaItems (if stored locally -- Array of URLs if online) to have a list of files to be played so that there is a next and back video to be played?

Comment: My videos are stored locally and yes i used array and url to play the videos.